# $\lim \limits_{x \to 0^+} (1+\tan^2(\sqrt{x}))^{\frac{1}{2x}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} (1+\tan^2(\sqrt{x}))^{\frac{1}{2x}}=?$$
$$x\in \langle0,+\infty\rangle$$

I know for sure $$1+\tan^2(\sqrt{x})>1\;\;\; \text{and}\;\;\;\tan(\sqrt{x})\;\;\text{oscilates from} -\infty\; \text{to}\; +\infty$$

$$y>1\implies \sqrt[2x]{y}>1$$

I got:
$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} (1+\tan^2(\sqrt{x}))^{\frac{1}{2x}}=\lim \limits_{x \to 0}e^{\ln{(1+\tan^2(\sqrt{x}))^{\frac{1}{2x}}}}=\lim \limits_{x \to 0}(e^{\frac{1}{2x}})^{\ln(1+\tan^2(\sqrt{x}))}=\infty$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that

$$(1+\tan^2(\sqrt{x}))^{\frac{1}{2x}}=\left[\left(1+\tan^2(\sqrt{x})\right)^{\frac1{\tan^2(\sqrt{x})}}\right]^{\frac{\tan^2(\sqrt{x})}{2x}} \to \sqrt e$$

indeed by standard limit $(1+x)^\frac1x\to e$

$$\left(1+\tan^2(\sqrt{x})\right)^{\frac1{\tan^2(\sqrt{x})}} \to e$$

and by standard limit $\frac{\tan x}{x}\to 1$

$$\frac{\tan^2(\sqrt{x})}{2x}=\frac12\frac{\tan (\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}\frac{\tan (\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}} \to \frac12$$

Comment: Thank you! So, it is the pattern:$ \;e=\lim \limits_{x \to 0} (1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\;$ ?

Comment: @VerkhotsevaKatya Yes of course from $$\lim_{y\to \infty} \left(1+\frac1y\right)^y=e$$ we obtain by $x=\frac1y \to 0$ that also $$\lim_{x\to 0} \left(1+x\right)^\frac1x=e$$ We don't need nothing else that standard limits in this case and we can (and should) avoid any other more advanced and unnecessary tool.

Comment: @VerkhotsevaKatya That's fine, try always to solve by standard limits. Only when you can't succed by that try with other more advance methods. You'll learn a lot about limits in this way.

Answer (score 3):

Write $$e^{\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{\ln(1+\tan^2\sqrt{x})}{2x}}$$ and use the rules of L'Hospital.

Comment: The question is about $ \lim \limits_{x \to 0^+} (1+\tan^2(\sqrt{x}))^{\frac{1}{2x}}$

Comment: I edited your nice answer as there were a minor typo.

Answer (score 2):

$\tan^2\sqrt x\sim x$ so $\ln(1+\tan^2\sqrt x)=x+o(x)$, so $1/(2x)
\ln(1+\tan^2\sqrt x)=1/2+o(1)$, so the limit is $e^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\ln(1+\tan^2(\sqrt{x}))}{2x}=$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\ln(1+\tan^2(\sqrt{x})}{\tan^2(\sqrt{x})}\frac{\tan^2(\sqrt{x})}{2(\sqrt{x})^2}$$

You should find that the limit is $\sqrt{e}$.